# Is it better to run a cron job every 3 minutes or do a php script only on request if 3 minutes already passed?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My problem is quite simple here: I have a php script which retrieves large quantity of csv files from different api, store them in a database (MySQL) and display them to my users. I have to query those api every 3 minutes to get significant data. **Only last data is used, no need to get historical data.**

**My concern is to avoid querying these api and inserting large amount of data in my database if no one is here to see the page.**

It is not a problem of rate limits, just thinking about reducing useless requests and inserts into a database.

My question is the following:

- Is it better to use a cron job every 3 minutes to retrieve data and store them OR
- run a php script if a page is loaded and 3 minutes have passed since last update?

In the first situation, every user will have the last values and data will always be retrieved even if no one is here to see them.
In the second situation, one user every 3 minutes will retrieve data for all (hence his page will be a little slower than others to load), but if no one is visiting the site, no useless data is stored.

Note:
Retrieving and inserting data take about 10 seconds.

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: using a cron job looks more solid solution

Comment: depends on your traffic + how long it takes to retrieve the data. can you quantify those?

Comment: It takes 10 seconds to retrieve data and insert them in the database. Traffic is very irregular, about 1000 unique ip/day: a lot during 9am to 4pm (US visitors), some from 3am to 11am (European ones) and few the rest of the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a combination of both.

If there is no traffic on your site, there is no need to keep the data current.

If there is traffic on your site, you need to keep the data current, but a three minute time-frame is enough for you.

So you need to fetch the data all three minutes if there was activity within the last X minutes.

If not, the first user will see a message that data is being prepared which only takes 10 seconds. You can then auto-refresh the website.

No current system exists that is able to perform this processing out of the box on your computer. Cron can help you do get the job done, but not alone.

Contact your system administrator and let make you suggestions what is available on the platform you operate on to fulfill your needs.

---

Actually this pretty much looks like caching. The CSV data has a life-time of 3 minutes, so you only need to cache the api response. If you use a caching server that is able to provide some logic (like varnish), you can configure prefetching relatively easily. Try to find some existing components you only need to configure and re-use instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I will look into varnish and cache systems, that's sound great! "The data is being prepared" is a good idea, i will use that while the user is waiting. Thanks!

Comment: If you can solve problems by communicating fair with the user, that is often very good not only for the usability, but also for the software you write. Imagine what a user wants, provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this line:

```
Note:
Retrieving and inserting data take about 10 seconds.
```

Cronjob will be the best. I don't think that visitors will be happy to wait 10s for a pageload every 3 minutes. What if I am the only one who is visiting your site and have to realod your script every 3 minutes over and over again ...

If the time would be 1 or 2s, then you could do it the other way.

Comment: I didn't think of a lonely visitor (but it's still likely!) ... yeah it would be a shame for him :/

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your Q correctly, you could consider making this 2 distinct tasks:

a) fetch the data and store it

b) process the data

Do a) every 3 minutes and do b) on request

Now check the delay on b) alone, then consider whether it is worth caching the result set.

Making it 2 distinct tasks will to have the benefit of to some degree insulating you from the vagaries of latency issues of fetching multiple files.  It can also give you a fall back in case of a data fetching failure "this data is more than 3 minutes old" as you process data from the last previous successful fetch.

Comment: The feature 'this data is more than 3 minutes old' is a very good idea! Actually I do the 2 distincts tasks and the first alone takes 10 seconds to perform while the second is very fast (few milliseconds). I will see the cache system if it's worth it... Thanks!

Comment: In effect the fetching and storage of the csvs is a form of caching.